# SQL: Update Column with increment numbers based on 2 Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 Columns and i need to reorder one of them with an Update statement.

Here is an Example:

**Date_time---------Priority**

20.07.2018           10

21.07.2018                   3

21.07.2018                   13

21.07.2018                   4

22.07.2018                   23

23.07.2018                   3

23.07.2018                   7

And i need to get this:

**Date_time---------Priority**

20.07.2018                   10

21.07.2018                   10

21.07.2018                   20

21.07.2018                   30

22.07.2018                   10

23.07.2018                   10

23.07.2018                   20

I need to change the Priority column based on current order and Date. The new order should be separated by 10... 10, 20, 30, 40, 50...

Can there someone help? Thanks.

Comment: 21.07.2018        3 why this updated by 10?

Comment: The priority is changed manual by users. I need to have space between first and second priority. When there are 2 priorities: 10 and 20 - the user can add another one in between with number 11. After reordering the new order should have 3 priorities in the list with numbers: 10, 20 and 30.

Comment: data type for column Date_time?

Comment: @VanjaVršić  can you check the answer

Comment: Data type is Datetime. But order should be only based on Date without time. Time doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try below query by using `row_number` funtion

```
update A
set Priority= 10*rn 
from TableA A inner join

( select  date_time, row_number() over(partition by Date_time order by Date_time  ) as rn from TableA
 ) as B
 on A.Date_time=B.Date_time
```

Comment: Thanks for help. With small changes i did finished the script. I needed to put order by Date_time, Priority DESC to get what i want. And also i made a small changes so the script can work with my Database.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Date_time] varchar(10), [Priority] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Date_time], [Priority])
VALUES
    ('20.07.2018', 10),
    ('21.07.2018', 3),
    ('21.07.2018', 13),
    ('21.07.2018', 4),
    ('22.07.2018', 23),
    ('23.07.2018', 3),
    ('23.07.2018', 7)
with cte as
(
SELECT *
    ,row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY REPLACE([Date_time], '.', '-') ORDER BY [Priority]
        ) AS rn
FROM #Table1
) select [Date_time],(10*rn) [Priority]  from cte
```

output

```
Date_time   (No column name)
20.07.2018  10
21.07.2018  10
21.07.2018  20
21.07.2018  30
22.07.2018  10
23.07.2018  10
23.07.2018  20
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `[Table Name]` with your table name

```
;with cte as 
(
select DENSE_RANK() over(partition by date_time order by priority)*10 as newPriority,date_time,priority from [Table Name]
)
update [Table Name] set [priority]= newPriority from cte 
where [Table Name].[priority]=cte.priority and [Table Name].Date_time=cte.Date_time
```